# how to fetch records from more than two different tables using hibernate which are not mapped

Tags: hibernate, jsp, hibernate-mapping

I am new to Hibernate. I have two tables named `questions` and `blogs`. These two tables are not mapped with each other. I want to fetch the records from these two tables  and sort them by created_date in hibernate.

Is there any solution for this??? I shall feel highly obliged for this act of your kind favor.

Answer (score 0):

If Hibernate Entity is available the query can be formed as below. It will return List.

> select qst.question, blg.link from Question qst, Blog blg  where
>   qst.createDate = blg.createDate order by blg.createDate

If Hibernate Entity is not available native sql can be used.